# How can I add spatial data to links in an OSM network from another network based on its attributes in R?

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph, dodgr

I have one OSM network which I divided into major and minor roads

```
osm_major <- osm[osm$highway %in% c("motorway","motowray_link","primary","primary_link","trunk","trunk_link"),]
osm_minor <- osm[!osm$highway %in% c("motorway","motowray_link","primary","primary_link","trunk","trunk_link"),]
```

I have traffic data in major roads and need to write these same data into the minor roads object, based on the connectivity of this network with the major roads, so the closest traffic value is reflected in each link of the minor road.

Is there some package to do this? and if yes, can you teach me how?

Comment: Could you maybe provide some sample data? I could try to answer your question using {sfnetworks}